# Populating a typeahead from a store to ComboBox

Tags: javascript, combobox, autocomplete, dojo

I'm trying to create a typeahead feature that queries a database to provide suggestions. The code below works in that each time a user types something into the combobox, the store is queried with the value of the combobox and it returns data successfully. so if the user types h in the box, the api is called like this:

```
          test/suggest?&q=h
```

and the data returned is in this format:

```
          {"content":[{"title":"hi"},{"title":"hello"}, {"title":"help"}]}
```

My problem is, how do I use this data to populate combobox suggestions?

```
    var store = new JsonRest({
        target: "test/suggest?"
    });

    var comboBox = new ComboBox({
        id: "stateSelect",
        name: "ourTestDojoTypeAhead",
        value: "",
        store: store,
        searchAttr: "q",
        hasDownArrow : false,
        enableKeyEvents: true

      } 
    }, "stateSelect");
```